# RemotingException Authentication failure .net

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I've been trying to get this remoting communication between my components (both on the same pc) and I got a bunch of different exceptions, I really have no clue what's going on since I haven't used remoting in a loong time, maybe you can give me a hand.

here's the stacktrace of the exception:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException was unhandled
  Message=Authentication failure
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
    Server stack trace: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.CreateAuthenticatedStream(Stream netStream, String machinePortAndSid)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.CreateSocketHandler(Socket socket, SocketCache socketCache, String machinePortAndSid)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.CreateSocketHandler(Socket socket, String machineAndPort)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket(AddressFamily family)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.CreateNewSocket()
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.RemoteConnection.GetSocket()
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.SocketCache.GetSocket(String machinePortAndSid, Boolean openNew)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.SendRequestWithRetry(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.ProcessMessage(IMessage msg, ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream requestStream, ITransportHeaders& responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.BinaryClientFormatterSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
    Exception rethrown at [0]: 
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
       at Persistencia.Factory.FactoryPersistencia.GetFachadaUsuario()
       at ConsolaPrueba.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Dropbox\Proyecto final 2014\ConsolaRedSocial\ConsolaPrueba\Program.cs:line 28
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
            at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, ChannelBinding binding, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
            at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.CreateAuthenticatedStream(Stream netStream, String machinePortAndSid)
       InnerException:
```

**this is the code I use for the Remoting server:**

```
BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider formatServ = new BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();

//propiedades nombre y puerto del servidor
IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
props["name"] = "Canal";
props["port"] = 8989;
try
{
    TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(props, null, formatServ);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
        typeof(FactoryPersistencia),
        "FabricaPersistencia",
        WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton
        );
    Console.WriteLine("Servidor de Remoting Levantado...");
    Console.WriteLine("Presione una tecla para terminar.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Here's the code I used for my client:**

```
TcpChannel chan = new TcpChannel();
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, true);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(FactoryPersistencia), "tcp://localhost:8989/FabricaPersistencia");

FactoryPersistencia fabricaPers = FactoryPersistencia.getInstance();


IPUsuario ipus = fabricaPers.GetFachadaUsuario();
```

**And here's the code to the Factory that's being called:**

```
public class FactoryPersistencia : MarshalByRefObject
{
    //Singleton
    private static FactoryPersistencia instancia = null;

    public static FactoryPersistencia getInstance(){

        if (instancia == null)
            instancia = (FactoryPersistencia)Activator.GetObject(typeof(FactoryPersistencia), "tcp://localhost:8989/FabricaPersistencia");

        return instancia;
    }

    public IPUsuario GetFachadaUsuario()
    {
        return new PersistenciaUsuario();
    }
    public IPEvento GetFachadaEvento() { 
        return new PersistenciaEvento();
    }
    public IPAmistad GetFachadaAmistad()
    {
        return new PersistenciaAmistad();
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone and I'm sorry I couldn't get the colouring to work, this is actually my first question here.

driden.

Comment: Are you using this for new development or are you maintaining a old program? [Microsoft has officially said you should not use Remoteing anymore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/72x4h507(v=vs.100).aspx) and it is only included in the framework for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Hi Scott! Thanks for replying. This is in fact, a project for the University. It's somewhat of a social network and I was specifically asked to use this technology despite being old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);` to `ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);` in your remoting server. Your client is asking for a secure channel but the server isn't providing one.

You can also remove `RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(FactoryPersistencia), "tcp://localhost:8989/FabricaPersistencia");` from your client.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Neil.
I'm getting this Exception now:
`System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: System.ArgumentNullException: No message was deserialized prior to calling the DispatchChannelSink. `

I couldn't paste the whole stacktrace due to character limitation. I'm still lost here.

Comment: @driden Does the `IPUsuario ipus = fabricaPers.GetFachadaUsuario();` succeed now? Which line throws the exception?

Comment: `public class FactoryPersistencia : MarshalByRefObject
    {   private static FactoryPersistencia instancia = null;
        private static HttpChannel chan;
        private FactoryPersistencia() {
            chan = new HttpChannel();
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(chan, true);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(typeof(FactoryPersistencia), "http://localhost:8585/FabricaPersistencia");
        }
        public static FactoryPersistencia getInstance()
        {if (instancia == null)
                instancia = new FactoryPersistencia();
          return instancia;}`

Comment: Wow that didn't come out formatted, anyways, in a nutshell what I did was change the channel to Http and removed one line I where I called the `instancia = (FactoryPersistencia)Activator.GetObject(typeof(FactoryPersistencia), "http://localhost:8585/FabricaPersistencia");`

Comment: @driden In your server you are using a `BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider` which is for Tcp. Change it to `SoapServerFormatterSinkProvider` which is for Http. Also change `ensureSecurity` to `false` on each of your channels, unless you are hosting in IIS.

Comment: I'll actually give a try to switch back to TCP for performance reasons. Thanks again.